# Check if postgresql database exists (case insensitive way)

Tags: postgresql, catalogs

Is there a "elegant built-in" case-insensitive way to check if db is exists?

I've found only `SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname='dbname'`, but this is a CS check.
The first thing that comes to mind to retrieve all db names and filter them by hand, but I think there is more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want a case insensitive check of a case sensitive item?

Answer (score 28):

You can use:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname) = lower('dbname');
```

... however, database names *are* case sensitive, so attempting to connect to the DB name won't actually work unless you match the case correctly. This won't use any indexes on `dbname`, but it's rather unlikely that you'd have enough databases for this to matter.

Folks don't realize that because PostgreSQL case-folds unquoted identifiers to lower-case, so most of the time it looks case-insensitive for clients. In fact, `"DatabaseName"` and `"databasename"` are different things.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a true/false answer you can use

```
select exists(
 SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname) = lower('dbname')
);
```